# OpenERP Home Action & Menu Action

Tags: odoo

I'm trying to customize users home page but without success so far.

I have tried a few values in both the "Home Action" and the "Menu Action" fields but I always get messaging feed on startup.

How can I customize this ???

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Home Action and Menu Action functionalities doesn't work for the web client. You can see why [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/openerp-web/+bug/962049). 
But you can change the sequence number in your menu item. the smallest sequence number is calling first.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please check this answer > https://launchpadlibrarian.net/155202728/patch.txt
For OpenERP 7.0
I have edited my chrome.js file  as show below and this patch works 

Added the Following code

//patch in function show_application



self.user_action_id = false ;
instance.web.blockUI();

var func = new instance.web.Model("res.users").get_func("read");
var home_action = func(self.session.uid, ['action_id']).then(function(result)
{
     action_id = result['action_id']
    if (action_id)
       {
           self.user_action_id = action_id[0]
            instance.web.unblockUI()
            self.bind_hashchange();
      }
     else{
            instance.web.unblockUI()
            self.bind_hashchange();
        }
    })
        // end of patch

****then replace contents in**** 


     self.menu.has_been_loaded.done(function() 
                {
                    var first_menu_id = self.menu.$el.find("a:first").data("menu");
                    if(first_menu_id) {
                        self.menu.menu_click(first_menu_id);
                    }
                });

**with below code.**



    self.menu.has_been_loaded.done(function() 
    {

        if (self.user_action_id){
                    self.action_manager.do_action(self.user_action_id, {'clear_breadcrumbs': true})
                    }
                    else{
                        var first_menu_id = self.menu.$el.find("a:first").data("menu");
                        if(first_menu_id) {
                            self.menu.menu_click(first_menu_id);
                        }
                     }
                 });
```